# Adding cookies to a cookiejar

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm playing around with requests.session() but I'm running into a few issues. I know that Session is supposed to handle the cookies for me, but I'm seeing that in some cases it isn't saving a certain cookie that the browser is. I wanted to see what would happen if I manually added or modified the cookies to match my browser but wasn't sure how to do it.

```
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[<Cookie bcookie="v=COOKIE" for .domain.com/>....
```

I imagine I need to decode the cookie to a string/dictionary, add/modify the cookie and then reencode it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `session.cookies` object gives you a mapping interface; to add cookies, just set a value for the cookie name:

```
session.cookies['cookie_name'] = 'cookie_value'
```

and leave it to `requests`.

In the other direction, using `session.cookies['cookie_name']` gives you the *just* the value for that cookie, without a need for you to learn about how the Python `CookieJar` object works and tracks all the other per-cookie metadata (such as host names and expiration information).

Comment: I'm noticing that my web browser creates a lot more cookies than when I do it via Requests. I'm getting an error / redirect page when I try it via ptyhon. Could the missing cookies be the reason why?

Comment: @MorganAllen: there can be **many** reasons why your request fails when using `requests`. The server is a black box, and how it responds to different requests can only be determined by trial and error, really. Use your browser development tools to see exactly what headers and POST data is sent and try out some of those headers. The User-Agent and Referer headers are two popular headers that servers vary responses on.

Comment: I got both User-Agent and Referer. I am able to log into the site using POST, but when I go to update some form data, it doesn't work. Is there anything I'm blatantly missing - headers via python, doesn't work - http://cl.ly/image/3p0K1H3A3G2A, headers via browser, works - http://cl.ly/image/0n3n123H340K

Comment: @MorganAllen: sorry, no ideas here. I'd sit down and test my assumptions about what cookies and headers are going back and forth, in detail. But that takes time and patience.

Comment: yea, thats what I've been doing. Linkedin is clearly looking for something I'm not providing in either the headers or cookies. I've been trying to set everything as the same, but to no luck :-(